# Expo camera breaks on mobile web version with React error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to use the `expo-camera` for web. For reference, this is working 100% on Expo Go on my phone. But when I visit my website (hosted on AWS) which has the same build, I get a white screen after accepting camera permissions because of this error

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the
> renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of
> Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to
> debug and fix this problem.

I can see in chrome tools (attached to my phone) this error, but it doesn't look like anything I am doing..

```
react-native-logs.fx.ts:34 Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at V (react.production.min.js:19)
    at Object.t.useRef (react.production.min.js:25)
    at ExponentCamera.web.tsx:30
    at na (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Ia (react-dom.production.min.js:176)
    at Bs (react-dom.production.min.js:271)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at _l (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at wl (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at dl (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
```

And this is the code it is referring to, which is of course part of expo

```
const ExponentCamera = React.forwardRef(
  (
    { type, pictureSize, poster, ...props }: CameraNativeProps & { children?: React.ReactNode },
    ref: React.Ref<ExponentCameraRef>
  ) => {
    const video = React.useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);

    const native = useWebCameraStream(video, type as CameraType, props, {
      onCameraReady() {
        if (props.onCameraReady) {
          props.onCameraReady();
        }
      },
      onMountError: props.onMountError,
    });
```

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationProp, ParamListBase } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { BarCodeScanningResult, Camera, PermissionResponse, PermissionStatus } from 'expo-camera';

export interface BarCodeScannerScreenProps {
    navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>
}

export const BarCodeScannerScreen = (props: BarCodeScannerScreenProps) => {
    const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = React.useState<string>(PermissionStatus.UNDETERMINED);

    const getPermission = async () => {
        const response: PermissionResponse = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        setCameraPermission(response.status);
    };

    const onBarCodeScanned = (event: BarCodeScanningResult) => {
        props.navigation.navigate("BookSearch", {searchValue: event.data});
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getPermission();
    }, []);

    if(cameraPermission === PermissionStatus.UNDETERMINED){
        return <Text>Requesting camera permission</Text>;
    }
    else if(cameraPermission === PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
        return (
            <Camera
                onBarCodeScanned={onBarCodeScanned}
                style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
            />
        );
    }
    else {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
}
```

Maybe I do have some invalid hook or something in my code? But I don't see why it would work fine on Expo Go.

Answer (score 1):

The recipe from a [React issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-983316545) worked for me:

```
expo customize:web
select webpack (PRESS SPACE)
enter
```

Then modify webpack.config.js file this way:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  // Customize the config before returning it.
  config.resolve.alias = {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
  }
  return config;
};
```